# Batch copying with xcopy - Renaming in use files

Tags: batch-file, copy, rename, xcopy

What I want to be able to do is have the script rename a files that are in use.

Is this possible?

This is my current script.
Thanks in advance!

```
@echo off
Set FileSource=C:\temp\cleric
Set RemoteDestinationFolder=C:\program files (x86)\cleric
Set InputFile=c:\Test\Computers.txt
Set RemoteDestination=\\%%*\%RemoteDestinationFolder::=$%\
For /F "eol=;" %%* in ('type "%InputFile%"') do (
 Ping.exe -n 2 -w 750 %%* | Find/i "TTL=" >Nul&&(
 xcopy /Y/q/r/e "%FileSource%" "%RemoteDestination%")||(
  echo.%%* "Computer was Not found">>%InputFile%.errors.log)
 If Not ErrorLevel 0 echo.%%* "Copy was unsuccesfull">>%InputFile%.errors.log
 (Set ErrorLevel=)
 )
@echo.
Pause
```

Comment: Files that are memory mapped (databases, program files, etc) can be renamed while in use (just do it). Files opened normally can't be, as it's a design feature to prevent corruption. Files may or may not be able to be copied depending on the flags passed by the opening program.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your reply.

The script uses a host file.

The idea is that I can put all of the host names into a text file and just set it away.
This can be run against 50+ machines, the file can be renamed manually but I want to save time.